# Is linear dual space a misleading term?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

A linear dual space consists of all linear functionals that sends a function in the space $X$ to its underlying field

But the linear space itself does not send element of the field to the space $X$, it  sends elements of space $X$ to space $Y$ instead

I had always thought that dual implied "symmetry", but instead it is another space entirely

What would be a "symmetrical" space called where the elements of a field is sent to space $X$? i.e. if we were to denote the linear space as $L(X,Y)$, what would be $L(Y,X)$ called?

Comment: A field is also a vector space over itself.

Comment: What do you means by ''a funcion in the space $X$'' ? A functional  send an element of $X$ to an element of the field $K$. Are you seing that  $X$ is a space of functions?

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question.

Comment: First of all, I think you misunderstand what "linear space" means. "Linear space" itself is just a synonym for "vector space", it needn't be a space consisting of linear operators between two vector spaces.

Comment: Secondly, we say "linear dual space" to distinguish from "continuous dual space". The linear dual space consists of *all* the linear functionals, while the continuous dual space consists of only the linear functionals which are continuous (which requires a topology, so this is not a purely algebraic notion).In finite dimensional normed spaces, these turn out to be equivalent. In infinite dimensional normed spaces, they are generally non-equivalent.

Comment: Thirdly, there is symmetry present. The symmetry comes about from the dual pairing, which is just the function $D : X \times X^* \to K$ with $D(x,f)=f(x)$. From this we get the notion of *adjoint*, which is really where the symmetry comes in: given a linear operator $A : X \to Y$, its adjoint is $A^* : Y^* \to X^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is actually isomorphic to the vector space of linear maps from the field into $X$. The bijection is given by sending a vector $v$ to the linear map that sends $1$ to $v$.